# How can I apply maths to a pandas dataframe comparing 2 specific row and column indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2022)

# make example data
close = np.sin(range(610)) + 10
high = close + np.random.rand(*close.shape)
open = high - np.random.rand(*close.shape)
low = high - 3
close[2] += 100  
dates = pd.date_range(end='2022-06-30', periods=len(close))

# insert into pd.dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates, data=np.array([open, high, low, close]).T, columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
print(df)
```

Output

```
                 Open       High       Low       Close
2020-10-29   9.557631  10.009359  7.009359   10.000000
2020-10-30  10.794789  11.340529  8.340529   10.841471
2020-10-31  10.631242  11.022681  8.022681  110.909297
2020-11-01   9.639562  10.191094  7.191094   10.141120
2020-11-02   9.835697   9.928605  6.928605    9.243198
...               ...        ...       ...         ...
2022-06-26  10.738942  11.167593  8.167593   10.970521
2022-06-27  10.031187  10.868859  7.868859   10.321565
2022-06-28   9.991932  10.271633  7.271633    9.376964
2022-06-29   9.069759   9.684232  6.684232    9.005179
2022-06-30   9.479291  10.300242  7.300242    9.548028
```

The goal here is to compare a specific value in the dataframe, to another value in the dataframe.

Edit:
I now know many different ways to achieve this however I have re-written the question so it is more clear for future readers what the original goal was.

For example:
Check when the value at 'open' column is less than the value at close column.

One solution for this is using itertuples, I have written an answer below explaining the solution

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Perhaps it's a good idea to read through the [Pandas user's guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html).

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear: you want to compare row A to row C, but then apply it to all rows? How would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in the question I have now found multiple solutions for this problem. One being itertuples.

Here is how to use itertuples to solve the problem.

First, create the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2022)

# make example data
close = np.sin(range(610)) + 10
high = close + np.random.rand(*close.shape)
open = high - np.random.rand(*close.shape)
low = high - 3
close[2] += 100
dates = pd.date_range(end='2022-06-30', periods=len(close))

# insert into pd.dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates, data=np.array([open, high, low, close]).T, columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
print(df)
```

Now we use itertuples to iterate over the rows of the dataframe

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    o = row.Open
    for r in df.itertuples():
        c = r.Close
        if o < c:
            print('O is less than C')
        else:
            print('O is greater than C')
```

This will find all instances of when the open price is less than the close price

This can be expanded on to check other conditions within the same loop just by adding more variables and more if statements, and also using enumerate to check positioning

For example:

```
for idx, row in enumerate(df.itertuples()):
    o = row.Open
    h = row.High
    for i, r in enumerate(df.itertuples()):
        c = r.Close
        l = r.Low
        if (i > idx) & ((h - 2) > l):
            if o < c:
                print('O is less than C')
            else:
                print('O is greater than C')
        else:
            continue
```

The above code uses enumerate to add a counter to each loop. The additional if statement will only check if 'o < c' in rows which the loop counter for 'c' is greater than the loop counter for 'o'.

As you can see any value in the dataframe can be compared to another using the correct if statements.

Answer (score 1):

The first step you want to do can be done by `df.loc["A", "High"] > df.loc["C", "Low"]`. To apply this to all rows you could do something like below:

```
for i in range(2, len(df)):
    print(df["High"][i-2] > df["Low"][i])
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do it, but this would work.

Comment: So id like to be able to apply the same formula to df.loc["B", "High"] > df.loc["D", "Low"] and then df.loc["C", "High"] > df.loc["E", "Low"] and so on across as many rows are as in the dataframe without having to write a line of code for every line of the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

you can use shift operation on column to shift the rows up/down

```
`df['High'] > df['Low'].shift(-2)`
```

To elaborate what's going on, run below commands

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,4), list('ABCDE'), ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
df['Low_shiftup'] = df['Low'].shift(-2)
df.head()
df['High'] > df['Low_shiftup']
```